# Parsing a valid normal-mode command (possibly with regex)? (for Vim-like Word add-in)

Tags: regular-expression, normal-mode, microsoft-windows, parsing

I am writing a VBA routine so I can use *normal-mode* commands in Microsoft Word.  (Yes, I am!  **Edit** And [here you go!](https://github.com/cxw42/VimWord))  I am only going to support the `d`, `c`, and `y` operators initially, and only char/word/sentence/paragraph motions.  No visual mode, no `]]` &c., no `"*`.

Is there an easy way to parse the command the user has entered?  My thought is that it probably can be done with a regex, since the count/operator/count/motion sequence is fairly restrictive.  Something like (very magic):

```
^([0-9]*)([dcy])([0-9]*)([ai][wWsp]|[hjklGfFtTwebWEB\)\(\}\{])$
```

Does anyone already have a regex or parser that will do this?  I am wondering if I have missed any corner cases or subtleties in the above.  (**Edit** For example, I had included `0` as a valid trailing character, which interacted badly with the `[0-9]*` before it.)  Thanks!

Comment: These seem like normal mode commands, not ex commands; please clarify.  Also since normal sequences form something of a finite state machine, it's plausible there may be such a regex, but I don't see how that helps you as opposed to hand-writing it.  FYI https://glts.github.io/2013/04/28/vim-normal-mode-grammar.html

Comment: @Mass Thanks for the correction.  Yes, normal mode, not ex mode.  Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written my [Word add-in](https://github.com/cxw42/VimWord) using VBScript regex v5.5 to parse the command.  Feedback and contributions welcome!  As of 2019-02-15, the add-in works in Word 2007–2016.  **Edit**  As of 2020-02-13, 64-bit Word is also supported.

I am largely following the model in [the grammar](https://glts.github.io/2013/04/28/vim-normal-mode-grammar.html) @Mass kindly linked to.  **As of [v0.2.9](https://github.com/cxw42/VimWord/releases/tag/v0.2.9)**, my regex is:

```
^(([1-9][0-9]*)?((([HMLGhjklwbWB\x28\x29\x7b\x7d]|g?[eE0\^\$]|[fFtT](.))|(gW)?g?[\*#]|g?[pP])|([cdyv])([1-9][0-9]*)?(([\[\]])?([ai])([wWsp])|[fFtT](.)|[HMLGhjklwbWB\x28\x29\x7b\x7d]|g?[eE0\^\$])))$
```

with *zero-based* submatch numbers:

```
1   The initial count

3   Intransitive verb (e.g., 0, w, f<char>)
4   Motion for an intransitive verb
5   The <char> of an f, F, t, or T

7   Transitive verb (e.g., operators d, c, y)
8   The count after the operator
9   The motion or text object ("target")
10  vim-ninja-feet* [ or ]
11  a or i if you are selecting a text object
12   For a and i motions, which type of object is being selected (w, W, s, p)
13  For f, F, t and T motions, which character is being used
```

<sup>* [vim-ninja-feet](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-ninja-feet)</sup>

Registers are still not supported.

The regex is complicated enough that I wrote a [Perl script](https://github.com/cxw42/VimWord/blob/master/re2vba.pl) to generate the regex from a text description of it.  That description is below.  Run `./re2vba.pl vim-regex.txt` to generate the regex and submatch-number assignments on stdout.

In the description, `(?<name>...)` represents a named submatch, and `(?<=piece-name)` pulls in a named piece of the regex.  Comments (`#...` or `(?#...)`) and trailing whitespace (after stripping comments) are ignored.

```
# Main pattern
main        ^(  (?# Note: registers not yet implemented)
                (?<count1>[1-9][0-9]*)?
                (?:
                    (?<=intrans)
                    |
                    (?<=trans)
                )
            )$

# Motions that don't take arguments (although they may take counts).
# A motion of "0" is special-cased in the parsing code to keep the regex
# clean.  This regex, after backtracking, matches "10" as a count of "1"
# followed by a "0" motion.  We special-case rather than handling that here.
noarg-motion    [HMLG
                hjkl
                wbWB
                \x28\x29\x7b\x7d]|
                    (?# 28/29 are parens, move sentence )
                    (?# 7b/7d are braces, move paragraph )
                g?[eE0\^\$]         (?# gw, gb, etc. are not motions.)
                (?#  ^ Note: 0 is special-cased in the parsing code.)

# Intransitive, including motions.  These can take a count, namely ?<count1>.
intrans     (?<iverb>
                (?<imotion>             (?# motions)
                    (?<=noarg-motion)|
                    [fFtT](?<itext>.)
                )|

                (gW)?g?[\*#]|           (?# searches)

                g?[pP]                  (?# pastes)
            )
                # IVERB: what to do
                        # ITEXT: character to jump to

# Text-object selection ([ai][something])
textobj     (?<ninja>[\[\]])?               (?# Ninja-feet marker)
                                    # https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-ninja-feet
            (?<tobj_range>[ai])             (?# Introducer)
            (?<objtype>[wWsp])              (?# Type of text object)

# Transitive: verb, count, object, object type, text
trans       (?<tverb>[cdyv])                (?# TVERB: what to do)
            (?<count2>[1-9][0-9]*)?         (?# Count after the operator)
            (?<target>                      (?# What to work on)
                (?<=textobj)|               (?# Text objects)
                [fFtT](?<ttext>.)|          (?# Motions with an argument)
                (?<=noarg-motion)
            )
```

Note 1: Just like in Vim, `v` selects the text moved over.  However, Word is essentially always in a combination of normal and visual modes, so `v` doesn't leave you in any special mode.

Note 2: I don't need the `c` intransitive verb for one-offs, since you are back in Word (i.e., insert mode) after a `d`.  However, I am working on a loop version that will leave you in Normal mode after a `d` but not after a `c`([#3](https://github.com/cxw42/VimWord/issues/3)).